# Laravel 5.3 Blade foreach loop : show data in loop from two different database eloquent queries

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

I have two tables.

1. contenttype
2. content

contenttype returns me list of content types and I show them on page with foreach. e.g. Ambulance service, Blood Bank , clinic etc. as shown in snapshot.

At the same time I am fetching total number of contents of each type from another table(contents).

I was successful to get total number of contents of each type and show on the blade with foreach. 
But situation is I want to show the number of contents on every content type.
Like this 
Ambulance sevice 8,
Blood Bank       7, 
Clinic           4.
My controller method is:

```
 public function index()
{
    if (Gate::allows('edit-content', auth()->user())) {
// below line returns list of content type e.g Ambulance service             

 $type = DB::table('contenttype')->distinct('label')->orderBy('label',     'asc')->paginate(10);

//below line counts the number of each content type e.g. Ambulance service 10.

$count = Content::selectRaw('type, count(*)total')->groupBy('type')->get();
return view('admin.content_listing', compact('type', 'count'));
    } else {
        abort(403, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

This is blade code:

```
@foreach ($count as $c)
  <span class="label label-danger">{{ $c->total }} </span>
@endforeach
```

This red number list is output: [image]

```
@foreach ($type as $t)
<div class="list-group-item">
<a href="{{ route('content.type.listing', $t->type  ) }}" > {{ $t->label }}
<span class=" pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></a>
<a href="{{ route('content.add.form') }}" class="pull-right "><span class="col-md-1 glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span></a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Output is: [image]
If I place above loop in second loop then Of course it will become nested loop that I don't want.

I need to show Ambulance 8,
Beauty clinic 8,
Blood Bank 1, 
etc.

If anybody knows the solution kindly share it!
I have tried different ways but no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than creating two queries and attempting to combine their results in the view, have you tried performing a join in a single query?  Making certain assumptions about your column names and leaving aside the pagination, the actual SQL would be something akin to:

```
SELECT contenttype.*, count(content.id) FROM contenttype LEFT JOIN content ON contenttype.id = content.type GROUP BY contenttype.label ORDER BY contenttype.label ASC;
```

The code necessary to implement this query with Laravel's query builder functionality is pretty well documented in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries).